# Parsing and displaying XML from httpGet

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

Hopefully someone can help me here. I have a project that I'm doing, yes it is homework so I hope that doesn't hurt my chances of an answer here. I'm supposed to write an app that collects data from bbyopen api. Best Buys web api, it delivers details about stores in your area. Any way I've gotten a response from the server that I'm certain contains the correct information as I've displayed it in logcat using System.out.println(). However, what I would like to do is turn this string into an xml document, parse out the name of the store, it's address and then display it in a text view in a new activity.

Here is the code I'm using to parse the string and put the proper data into an array which is passed to a new activity. I'm certain that nothing is actually passed to the new activity and I'm unsure whether or not the array is even being built. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void callback(String serviceResult){
        System.out.println(serviceResult);

        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory parserCreator = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            parserCreator.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser parser = parserCreator.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(new StringReader(serviceResult));
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != parser.END_DOCUMENT){
                String name = "";
                String address = "";
                if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)&& (parser.getName().equals("longName"))){
                    name = parser.getName();
                }
                if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)&& (parser.getName().equals("address"))){
                    address = parser.getName();
                    Store store = new Store(name, address);
                    arrStore.add(store);
                    System.out.println(arrStore);
                }
                else
                    parser.nextTag();

            }

        }  catch (Exception e) {

        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StoreList.class);
        intent.getStringArrayListExtra(arrStore.toString(), "key");
        startActivity(intent);



    }
```

I then receive the intent in the new activity like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store_list);
        getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> store = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key");


    }
```

However trying to do a print line on the ArrayList store, in the new activity results in a null pointer error. I suspect that is because the array is empty..?

If it helps here is what the XML that I am receiving looks like and it is being sent as a string the parser.

```
<stores warnings="Distances are in terms of miles (default)" currentPage="1" totalPages="1" from="1" to="4" total="4" queryTime="0.006" totalTime="0.011" >
  <store>
    <longName>Best Buy - Toledo II</longName>
    <address>1405 Spring Meadows Dr</address>
  </store>
  <store>
    <longName>Best Buy - Perrysburg</longName>
    <address>10017 Fremont Pike</address>
  </store>
  <store>
    <longName>Best Buy - Toledo</longName>
    <address>4505 Monroe St</address>
  </store>
  <store>
    <longName>Best Buy Mobile - Franklin Park</longName>
    <address>5001 Monroe Street</address>
  </store>
</stores>
```

Comment: I actually think I have a bunch of problems here... I just added a count variable to see how many times I check the tag name and I'm only looping once...

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StoreList.class);
intent.getStringArrayListExtra(arrStore.toString(), "key");
startActivity(intent);
```

Try: [putStringArrayListExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29).